# NodeJs : Code sometimes work - Async.map issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a config json file as below.

```
"constraints": {
    "input": "input",
    "output": "output"
  }
```

I am trying to read this file and create `input` and `output` directory with child directories.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");
var node_xj = require("xls-to-json");
var cf= JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("config.json", 'utf8'));

// Declare variables
var files = [];    

function readAsync(file, callback) {
    node_xj(file, callback);        
} 

function create(currentDirPath, outputDirPath, callback) {  
// some code creating directories
}    

create(cf.lang.input, cf.lang.output, function(stat, config) {
    files.push(config); 
});  

async.map(files, readAsync, function(err, results) {
     if(err) throw err;
});
```

**The code works fine, but its sometimes does not.** Let me walk through the code. I am loading some modules.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");
var node_xj = require("xls-to-json");
```

I am loading the config file.

```
var cf= JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("config.json", 'utf8'));
```

Then i am passing the cf file to create function which after its operation returns me an an `object` which i push it into an `array`.

```
var files = [];    
function readAsync(file, callback) {
    node_xj(file, callback);        
} 

function create(input, output, callback) {  
   // some code creating directories and object
}    

create(cf.lang.input, cf.lang.output, function(stat, config) {
    files.push(config); 
});  

async.map(files, readAsync, function(err, results) {
     if(err) throw err;
});
```

Then i am passing the files array to my `async.map` function which passes it to `readAsync` function for another operation.

Question:

1. Can anyone tell me whether **the way** i have written the code flow
   makes if flaw sometimes.
2. Is there a better way of writing the same code logic flow.
3. Should i use async.map to iterate files and then pass it to
   readAsync

Answer (score 1):

If you're depending on asynchronous operations to occur before other operations, you have to treat them asynchronously! Your code as described seems to create some directories (which will take measurable time) and immediately attempts to use them, which isn't kosher.

You might consider something like:

```
async.series([
  function(){
    // create your directories here
  },
  function(){
    async.map(files,...)
  }
]);
```

which will guarantee that the resources needed by your map exist before the map is called.

Comment: Thanks, in this series... how will i pass my config param to my function? I am not not quite getting it... is it possible can you give a little more code on the same converting mine? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, if you could provide a clear explanation of what you're trying to accomplish. For example, you have a function `readAsync()` which doesn't *read* anything. Rather is converts an xsl file into JSON but doesn't indicate where that file came from. ;) IF you can provide a list of steps of what you need to accomplish, I'd be happy to show you how.